# Am I placing these commas correctly?

Tags: punctuation

My passion, however, is art, and I try to see as many exhibits as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your comma placement is correct.

You need a comma before the *and* because it is a coordinate conjunction joining two independent clauses. The two parts of the sentence are complete sentences on their own, and when independent clauses are joined by a coordinate conjunction (like *and*, *but*, *or*, etc.) you need a comma before the conjunction.

*However* is an interjection here and also needs to be set off by commas.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's correct, but to reduce the number of commas, maybe you could say: "My passion is art, however, and I try to see as many exhibits as possible."